# Why is branching recursion faster than linear recursion (example: list inversion)

Tags: python, performance, recursion

Yesterday I wrote two possible reverse functions for lists to demonstrate some one different ways to do list inversion. But then I noticed that the function using branching recursion (`rev2`) is actually faster than the function using linear recursion (`rev1`), even though the branching function takes more calls to finish and the same number of calls (minus one) of non-trivial calls (that are actually more computation intensive) than the non-trivial calls of the linearly recursive function. Nowhere am I explicitly triggering parallelism, so where does the performance difference come from that makes a function with more calls that are more involved take less time?

```
from sys import argv
from time import time


nontrivial_rev1_call = 0 # counts number of calls involving concatentation, indexing and slicing
nontrivial_rev2_call = 0 # counts number of calls involving concatentation, len-call, division and sclicing

length = int(argv[1])


def rev1(l):
    global nontrivial_rev1_call

    if l == []:
        return []
    nontrivial_rev1_call += 1
    return rev1(l[1:])+[l[0]]

def rev2(l):
    global nontrivial_rev2_call
    if l == []:
        return []
    elif len(l) == 1:
        return l
    nontrivial_rev2_call += 1
    return rev2(l[len(l)//2:]) + rev2(l[:len(l)//2])



lrev1 = rev1(list(range(length)))
print ('Calls to rev1 for a list of length {}: {}'.format(length, nontrivial_rev1_call))


lrev2 = rev2(list(range(length)))
print ('Calls to rev2 for a list of length {}: {}'.format(length, nontrivial_rev2_call))  
print()

l = list(range(length))


start = time()
for i in range(1000):
    lrev1 = rev1(l)
end = time()

print ("Average time taken for 1000 passes on a list of length {} with rev1: {} ms".format(length, (end-start)/1000*1000))


start = time()
for i in range(1000):
    lrev2 = rev2(l)
end = time()

print ("Average time taken for 1000 passes on a list of length {} with rev2: {} ms".format(length, (end-start)/1000*1000))
```

Example call:

> ```
> $ python reverse.py 996
> calls to rev1 for a list of length 996: 996   
> calls to rev2 for a list of length 996: 995
>
> Average time taken for 1000 passes on a list of length 996 with rev1: 7.90629506111145 ms
> Average time taken for 1000 passes on a list of length 996 with rev2: 1.3290061950683594 ms
> ```

Comment: Because each call you copy the list, and copying happens in *O(n)*.

Comment: But I do that in both functions. The branching version merely splits the load over several 'parallel' calls.

Comment: Instead of just counting the number of function calls in your two routines, count up the total number of list-items copied across all the calls in each routine.

Comment: Good catch that you noted the perf difference, curious what this results are over a large repeated execution set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer**: It's not that much the calls here, but it is the **amount of copying of the lists**. As a result the **linear recursion** has time complexity ***O(n<sup>2</sup>)*** wheras the **branching recursion** has time complexity ***O(n log n)***.

The recursive call here does *not* operate in constant time: it operates in the *length of the list it copies*. Indeed, if you copy a list of *n* elements, it will require *O(n)* time.

Now if we perform the linear recursion, it means we will perform *O(n)* calls (the maximum call depth is *O(n)*). Each time, we will copy the list entirely, except for one item. So the time complexity is:

```
 n
---
\        n * (n+1)
/    k = -----------
---           2
k=1
```

So the time complexity of the algorithm is - given the calls itself are done in *O(1)* - *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*.

In case we perform branching recursion, we make two copies of the list, each with a length that is approximately half. So every *level* of recursion will take *O(n)* time (since these halves result in copies of the list as well, and if we sum these up, we make an entire copy at every recursive level). But the **number of levels** scales logwise:

```
log n
-----
\      
/      n = n log n
-----
k=1
```

So the time complexity is here *O(n log n)* (here *log* is the 2-log, but that does not matter in terms of *big oh*).

## Using views

Instead of copying lists, we can use *views*: here we keep a reference to the *same* list, but use two integers that specify the span of the list. For example:

```
def rev1(l, frm, to):
    global nontrivial_rev1_call
    if frm >= to:
        return []
    nontrivial_rev1_call += 1
    result = rev1(l, frm+1, to)
    result.append(l[frm])
    return result

def rev2(l, frm, to):
    global nontrivial_rev2_call
    if frm >= to:
        return []
    elif to-frm == 1:
        return l[frm]
    nontrivial_rev2_call += 1
    mid = (frm+to)//2
    return rev2(l, mid, to) + rev2(l, frm, mid)
```

If we now run the `timeit` module, we obtain:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(partial(rev1, list(range(966)), 0, 966), number=10000)
2.176353386021219
>>> timeit.timeit(partial(rev2, list(range(966)), 0, 966), number=10000)
3.7402000919682905
```

This is because we no longer copy the lists, and thus the `append(..)` function works in *O(1)* *amortized* cost. Whereas for the branching recursion, we append two lists, so it works in *O(k)* with *k* the sum of the length of the two lists. So now we compare *O(n)* (linear recursion), with *O(n log n)* (branching recursion).